# Error unexpected token: com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0 @ line 40, column 21. in build.gradle

Tags: java, android, android-studio, zxing

I was following a tutorial to build an android-base QR code scanner in android studio. However, when I try to implement Zxing in my build.gradle(app) file, I got error display:

unexpected token: com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0 @ line 40, column 21.
         Implementation'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'

Here is the code in gradle.build file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'



        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
         'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

        //add this dependency
      Implementation'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the log the problem is at this line,

`Implementation'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'`

replace it with

`implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'`

The change is in the implementation keyword and there has to be exactly one space between implementation keyword and the name of the dependency.